# Is there a voice action shortcut in ICS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-voice-actions

Android 4.0 doesn't have a magnifying glass search button like most pre-ICS phones.  I'm actually one of the people who used the long-press search button often with [voice actions](http://www.google.com/mobile/voice-actions/).

Is there a similar shortcut in ICS, now that it doesn't have the search button, or am I stuck going back to the home screen/app list?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the Galaxy Nexus?  On your home screen you will see the "Google Search" bar.  On the right, inside this bar, you will see a microphone symbol.  Tap it.

I believe you are stuck going back to this screen.

Comment: Not directing this at you Wayne but I want to comment and don't want to leave this as an answer. 

Using the search bar is a horrible step backwards in user experience. I used the magnifying glass many times per day to do searches and set alarms with voice actions. I really hope I can find a way to get this back next to the hardware soft keys.